# Minimum of two convex functions

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I'm having trouble showing the below statement is true.

$\hat{\alpha}=\arg\min_\alpha \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} f(u_i - h(v_i, \alpha))$ where $h(v_i, \alpha)$ is linear in $\alpha$.

$\hat{\alpha}^*=\arg\min_\alpha \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^{n} g(u_i - h(v_i, \alpha))$ where $g(v_i, \alpha)$ is linear in $\alpha$.

The functions $f$ and $g$ are convex where $g$ is a smooth approximation of $f$ such that $|f(x)-g(x)|< k/2$

Show that $\hat{\alpha}^* \rightarrow \hat{\alpha}$ as $k \rightarrow 0$.

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks.